# Calling an object function before declaring it

Tags: c++, function, object

Hi I want to call an objects function in other function but i can't. Why ?

```
class class1
{
private:
    int var;
public:
    class1(int x);
    void functionO();
};

class1::class1(int x)
{
    var = x;
}

void class1::functionO()
{
    cout<<"text";
}

void Callfunction()
{
    object1->function0();
}

int main()
{
    class1 *object1;

    object1 = new class1(x);

    Callfunction();
}
```

Compilator says that

> 'object1' : undeclared identifier

It seems logical but how can i call that objects function within a function ?

Comment: It's simply not in that scope. If you need to share variables use a parameter, or *shudder* a global.

Comment: You don't need that `new`, and you're not freeing that memory. Use `class1 object1(x);`.

Comment: Are you perhaps coming from java or c#? Because `object1 = new class1(x);` is just unneeded complexity. Go simply with `class1 object1(x);`

Comment: As a side note: I suggest not using "O" at the end of your function name, since it can easily be confused with the numeral "0". Which it appears you have already done.

Answer (score 3):

In this code:

```
void Callfunction()
{
    object1->function0();
}
```

`object1` is out-of-scope.  That is, the compiler doesn't know about anything named `object1` from within the scope of `CallFunction()`.

Note that even if you had defined `CallFunction` *after* `main()`, this would still be true.  All variables are local to the scope in which they are declared.

One option is to make `object1` a global, and I'm sure that you will be advised to do this.  But please don't.  Global variables introduce state to your program, and along with it a host of other nasty problems that are hard to fix without tearing your program apart.  Don't get in to the habit of using global variables to fix all manner of scoping issues.  You will regret it.

Rather, why not just pass a `class1` pointer to `CallFunction()`?  Better yet, pass a reference.

```
void CallFunction(class1& obj1)
{
  obj1.function0();
}

int main()
{
    class1 *object1;

    object1 = new class1(x);

    Callfunction(*object1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your object as (reference) parameter to your function:

```
class class1
{
private:
    int var;
public:
    class1(int x);
    void function0();
};

class1::class1(int x)
: var(x) // Note: Use member initializer lists
{}

void class1::function0()
{
    std::cout << "text, var = " << var << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
void Callfunction(class1& object)
{
    object.function0();
}
```

---

```
int main()
{
    class1 object1(10);
    class1 object2(42);

    Callfunction(object1);
    Callfunction(object2);
}
```

Expected output:

```
text, var = 10
text, var = 42
```

**NOTE**
The declaration order also matters, you might need to use a forward declaration when `class1` is declared after the compiler sees `Callfunction()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the declaration order (before or after doesn't matter). Your `object1` is a local variable of `main`. This means that it isn't visible outside of `main`, unless you explicitely pass it to the function needing it or store a pointer to it in a global variable (but please don't). To solve your problem you should therefore pass your object to `Callfunction`:

```
void Callfunction(class1& object1)
{
    object1.function0();
}

int main()
{
    class1 object1(x);//<-- This asumes that you have actually defined x 
                      //somewhere, otherwise replace it with an actual value
    Callfunction(object1);
}
```

Note that I took the liberty of clearing up the unneeded indirection (and the memory leak) by constructing the object on the stack instead of on the heap.